# Equivalent of self.window.rootViewController for self.view addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to use this control in my app

https://github.com/pyro2927/GKLParallaxPictures

My app is using Storyboards. In the viewDidLoad of the View I wish to use GLKParallaxPictures is have the following code:

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300-g.jpg"];
NSArray *photosArray1 = @[testImage, testImage, testImage];

GKLParallaxPicturesViewController *paralaxViewController = [[GKLParallaxPicturesViewController alloc] initWithImages:photosArray1                                                                                                   andContentWebView:webView];

[self.view addSubview:paralaxViewController.view];
```

The last line of the code above throws an exception.

In the original example of the control the author has the following code in AppDelegate

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shovel"];
NSArray *images = @[testImage, testImage, testImage];

GKLParallaxPicturesViewController *paralaxViewController = [[GKLParallaxPicturesViewController alloc] initWithImages:images
                                                                                                      andContentWebView:testWebView];
self.viewController = paralaxViewController;

self.window.rootViewController = paralaxViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Can u post the exception please?

Comment: [self presentViewController: paralaxViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x565793f5)

Comment: Dear MSK, that was it! Can you place your comment as an answer please?

Comment: The only problem is that I lose the NavigationBar for that view. Any ideas why?

Comment: Of course, you are presenting it modally. It is a totally different thing from adding the component as a subview.

Comment: I think the error is the fact that u are adding the SAME INSTANCE three times to the array. Try to add 3 separate instances.

Comment: Dear Raphael, that is not the problem. It just shows the same image three times for the sake of an example.

Comment: How to I add it as a subview? I dont want to present it modally. I need the NavigationBar.